# Automatic slider scrolling doesn't work correct

Tags: javascript, html, slider

*Hi!I try to create a  automatic scrolling slider. So it works good, but

when it comes to the last slide it does not switch to the first but stops. Look at my html and JavaScript code, i think that the problem is in JS code. Thanks:*

```js
var inputs = $('input');
    setInterval(()=>{
        var next = inputs.filter(":checked").next('input');
        if (!next.length) next=inputs.first();
        next.prop('checked', true);
    }, 300);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <input type="radio" name="slides" id="slide1" checked>
  <input type="radio" name="slides" id="slide2" >
  <input type="radio" name="slides" id="slide3" >
  <input type="radio" name="slides" id="slide4" >
  <input type="radio" name="slides" id="slide5" >
  <input type="radio" name="slides" id="slide6" >

  <div class="slider_helper">

      <div class="captions">
        <div class="c2">Prediction 2</div>
        <div class="c3">Prediction 3</div>
        <div class="c4">Prediction 4</div>
        <div class="c5">Prediction 5</div>
        <div class="c6">Prediction 6</div>
      </div>

      <div class="img img1"></div>
      <div class="img img2"></div>
      <div class="img img3"></div>
      <div class="img img4"></div>
      <div class="img img5"></div>
      <div class="img img6"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="side-controls">
    <label for="slide1"></label>
    <label for="slide2"></label>
    <label for="slide3"></label>
    <label for="slide4"></label>
    <label for="slide5"></label>
    <label for="slide6"></label>
  </div>

  <div class="controls">
    <label for="slide1"></label>
    <label for="slide2"></label>
    <label for="slide3"></label>
    <label for="slide4"></label>
    <label for="slide5"></label>
    <label for="slide6"></label>
  </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: there is no problem it's working fine check here http://jsfiddle.net/b307yphm/

Comment: but it doesn't works correct on codepen https://codepen.io/diesel9/full/BqWOGK where is the mistake?

Comment: See my answer `input[type=radio]` https://stackoverflow.com/a/52872664/5830472

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Input Type in to radio   `input[type=radio]`

```
var inputs = $('input[type=radio]');
    setInterval(()=>{
        var next = inputs.filter(":checked").next('input');
        if (!next.length) next=inputs.first();
        next.prop('checked', true);
    }, 500 );
```

Comment: Great! Works now! But it is strange why it  works good there without 'input[type=radio]'  http://jsfiddle.net/b307yphm/

Comment: Good . Set as the answer. Yes it will work fine for the first time. There are many Input tags. We need to specify only slides

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var inputs = $('input');
 var currentInput = inputs.first();
    setInterval(()=>{
        currentInput.prop('checked', true);
        if (currentInput.index()==inputs.last().index()) {
            currentInput = inputs.first();
        } else
            currentInput = inputs.filter(":checked").next('input');
    }, 300);
</script>
```

Comment: nothing changes. Probably the problem is in Codepen? I run this code there. https://codepen.io/diesel9/full/BqWOGK

Comment: The problem in that whole code is that you have more inputs, you have to focus in radio inputs only